# How do I export multiple objects with animations in one FBX?

Tags: animation, export, rigid-body-simulation, .fbx

The following problem: I have made a granule simulation and then converted the simulation to keyframes. So now each granule piece has its own animation. Now I want to export all granule pieces including their animations as one FBX and then import them into Keyshot.
Is it possible to export all granules as 1 FBX without losing the animations?

I tried this with a few granule pieces and then imported the FBX back into Blender and unfortunately all the granule pieces are stuck together (Screenshot). If I use "Copy" for Path Mode, then I can export the animation from one granule piece correctly. But if I export multiple objects using "Copy" then unfortunately the same thing happens as before.

Does anyone know a solution for this problem? If so, please send it to me :D
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to BSE! Have you tried exporting as Alembic (.abc)?

Comment: Wow, thank you very much, that works without problems and is also extremely fast. Is it always best to use .abc for animations?

Comment: I'm no expert with these formats. The fbx and abc formats are both popular choices for exporting animation and have their advantages and disadvantages. I would consult google for their differences and when to decide when to use which format.